# Get print from printer using android via USB

Tags: android, printing, usb-drive

I want to bring a functionality to my Android app, that users can connect from mobile device (mobile or tablet) via USB and can take out the prints. Please do me a favour, need link or code.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: did u find solution.I am looking similar one.